# Shipping to US only in Magento

Tags: e-commerce, magento

I have a client that wants to only sell/ship their goods to customers within the United States.
How to limit shipping to only within the U.S.A. on Magneto Community Edition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System > Configuration > General > "Allow Countries"`

[image: Countries Allowed in Magento]

Comment: philwinkle will this limit access to the site to only those selected aso or just limit checkout from those countries?

Comment: It only limits shipping destination in the checkout!